# Graphing Exponent functions with function-plot.js

Tags: javascript, plot, graph

I'm encountering something that I'm certain is a bug. I'm using function-plot.js to represent the graphs, since I need some of the functionality it provides, though the equations I'm working with don't seem to play nice. When I try send the equation(2^x) into it, it doesn't display it on the page--however, it will track where the line is supposed to be, as well as track the slope that is derived from the derivative. Furthermore, when I give it a simpler equation (such as x^2), it will render and display the graph as per normal.

The function with the data I'm using is here:

```
functionPlot({
    target: root,
    yAxis: {
        domain: [-1, 9]
    },
    tip: {
        renderer: function () {}
    },
    grid: true,
    data: [{
        fn: "2^x",
        derivative: {
            fn: "2^x",
            updateOnMouseMove: true
        },
    }]
});
```

So if anyone could tell my why it is not displaying the function that would be lovely, since I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and when I went reading through the documentation it didn't mention anything about using exponentiation with the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out the issue, I needed to include graphType: 'polyline' in the code, as such.

```
 functionPlot({
    target: root,
    yAxis: {
        domain: [-1, 9]
    },
    tip: {
        renderer: function () {}
    },
    grid: true,
    data: [{
        fn: "2^x",
        derivative: {
            fn: "2^x",
            updateOnMouseMove: true
        },
        graphType: 'polyline'
    }]
});
```